# Php Ldap Sanitizing and ldap bind

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate users with ldap. I have the above code for sanitizing the user input.

```
function ldapSanitize($val) {
    $sanitized=array('\\' => '\5c',
                     '*' => '\2a',
                     '(' => '\28',
                     ')' => '\29',
                     "\x00" => '\00');

    return str_replace(array_keys($sanitized),array_values($sanitized),$val);
```

I call the ldapSanitize for the username and the password like this

```
$uname = ldapSanitize($username);
$pass = ldapSanitize($password);
```

and the I use bind to authenticate a user

```
 $ad = @ldap_connect(Config::ldaphost);
    if ($ad) {
        $bind = @ldap_bind($ad, $uname, $pass);
        if ($bind) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

My problem is that if the password has the * character it transforms it to \2a and the authentication fails. for example if the password is "somepassword*" it changes it to "somepassword\2a" and the bind fails.

So I was wondering how I can sanitize the password but also be able to authenticate with bind.

Answer (score 0):

You should not sanitize passwords.
RFC 4511 says that textual passwords should be transfered as UTF-8. Non textual password must not be altered.

LDAP servers treat passwords as octet strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant paragraph from RFC 4511 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.2):

```
 Textual passwords (consisting of a character sequence with a known
 character set and encoding) transferred to the server using the
 simple AuthenticationChoice SHALL be transferred as UTF-8 [RFC3629]
 encoded [Unicode].  Prior to transfer, clients SHOULD prepare text
 passwords as "query" strings by applying the SASLprep [RFC4013]
 profile of the stringprep [RFC3454] algorithm.  Passwords
 consisting of other data (such as random octets) MUST NOT be
 altered.  The determination of whether a password is textual is a
 local client matter.
```

Note that it states that the 'client should prepare text passwords as "query" strings' and references other standards.